# is it possible to see the Logcat on Google TV device?

Tags: android, google-tv, android-logcat

I am building an app for Google TV.

The app runs fine on emulator but causes crashes on actual Google TV device. I am unable to see what caused the issues. I was wondering if there is any way to see the Logcat on actual google tv device so i can see what caused the crash?

**EDIT: code and error details can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279626/android-listview-item-selection-issue-in-google-tv)**

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way, but if you want you can just view it on your computer via "adb logcat".  Plan B

Comment: code and error details can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279626/android-listview-item-selection-issue-in-google-tv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is any way to see the Logcat on actual google tv device so i can see what caused the crash?

Yes, the same way you view LogCat for any other Android device. However, you need to set up your Google TV to allow debugging from your development machine (via Settings), and you need to run `adb connect <ipaddr>` to make the connection, where `<ipaddr>` is the IP address of the Google TV box.

Comment: thanks ... though i have sorted out the issue that was crashing the app ... but ur question clarifies what i was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of google tv devices (I don't even own a TV so I bet I'll never have a google TV ;) ).

But, for sure, if it's running android, then you should be install this log act viewer : [cat log](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=fr).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but you probably need some form of license key or something like when you use Google maps, they give you a development key but when you launch the app on market you need an actual key.

Comment: no brother ... i m not using Google maps... i have updated my question .. u can see detail in the provided link ... thanks