# android:state_activated not found

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My android project minimum API 10. Support v4 included. 
In the android doc i found selector state "activated"
[image]

But when i try use it, IDE mark it as missed.

[image]

Here [https://stackoverflow.com/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205339/listview-item-selected-state-not-working)
and here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279626/android-listview-item-selection-issue)
this state looks like a solution to my problem, but i can not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it may be a bug in the docs. It shows it from the screen you are showing but if you go to the `R.attr` class and look at the corresponding variable then it is greyed out with `API 10` selected and to the left it shows requires `API 11`

[image]

Sorry, my graphic arts skills aren't great but zoom in and you will see.

[Here is a solution](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/selectablelistview-make-selection-work/) that may or may not work for what you need. I didn't read through the whole example but you can give it a look.

And [Here is a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531272/state-activated-on-pre-honeycomb-devices) dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your build target in eclipse. Right click the project and click `Properties`. Then select `Android` from the tree on the left. You can then select the target version on the right.